# GridSearchCV without Cross Validation CV = 1

Tags: deep-learning, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I have a special dataset and this dataset could be trains with a %1 error. I need to do hyperparameter tuning for MLPRegressor without a split train set. Meanly cv = 1. Is this possible with GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 2):

One of the options for `cv` parameter is:

> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

So, if you have `X` input matrix, `y` target vector, `mlp` classifier, and `params` grid you can do just one train-test split.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

indices = np.arange(len(X))
train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(indices, test_size=0.2)
clf = GridSearchCV(mlp, params, cv=[(train_idx, test_idx)])
```

But keep in mind that using 1 split for hyper-parameter sweep is a bad practice. Do not make many steps with such a grid search.